# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnProperty not resolving property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

In my Spring Boot project (SB v2.4.4) I'm trying to conditionally enable a configuration class using `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "feature1.enabled",
        havingValue = "true",
        matchIfMissing = false
)
@Configuration
public class NewConfig {
    ...
}
```

Property `feature1.enabled` is declared in a `features.properties` file that is loaded using a second configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:features.properties")
public class FeaturesConfig {
}
```

Properties declared in `features.properties` are correctly loaded, but `@ConditionalOnProperty` doesn't seem to resolve `feature1.enabled`.

I also tried to annotate `NewConfig` class with a `@DependsOn("featuresConfig")`, but nothing changes.

The only thing that seems to work is to move `feature1.enabled` in `application.properties`.

So why this is not working? What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Because the properties with `@PropertySource` are loaded after all `@Conditional`s are checked. So putting that in a properties file that isn't loaded as part of Spring Boot won't work. You will need to add it as additional properties file to spring boot using the proper commandline arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by *M.Denium* in his comment, I solved the issue adding this command line argument on application launch:

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:/features.properties
```

adding `features.properties` file as an additional configuration location for my application, fixes the property resolution issue in `@ConditionalOnProperty`.